How to assign array values in rosmsg result part of message in actionlib in Rospy (ROS 1 in python)
Good day all,
I'm trying to create an action server that sends three float64 vectors each containing the x, y and z coordinates of a point following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kjJ3eJrZKo&t=69s
$ rosmsg show skelePCResult

[mrm_telescoping/skelePCResult]:
float64[] x
float64[] y
float64[] z

Here are the contents of the action file skelePC.action
#Receive 1 if requesting for skeleton of tree (goal)
int8 request_skel
---
#Send vectors of skeleton points (result)
float64[] x
float64[] y
float64[] z
---
#Send 1 if successful (response)
int8 feedback_skel

I was wondering ho do I or set the variables in my callback function for the (result) variables x,y,z as a skelPCActionResult() object.
import rospy
import actionlib
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
import time

class ActionServer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_server = actionlib.SimpleActionServer("skelPC_as", skelPCAction, execute_cb = self.execute_cb, auto_start = False)
        self.a_server.start()

    def execute_cb(self, goal): #When this function is called, we receive a goal
        success = True
        feedback_skel = skelPCActionFeedback() #Feedback ac
        result_x = skelPCActionResult().x #Result ac
        result_y = skelPCActionResult().y
        result_z = skelPCActionResult().z
        rate = rospy.Rate(1)

        if goal.request_skel == 1: #if requesting #Request ac
            if self.a_server.is_preempt_requested(): #If user cancels
                success = False
                feedback_skel = 0
                break
            #else: fill up result x,y and z vectors of skeleton points
            rate.sleep()
        
        if success:
            #Publish result here
            self.a_server.set_suceeded(result_x, result_y, result_z)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rospy.init_node("action_server")
    s = ActionServer()
    rospy.rospy()

Thank you!
